# Is this efficient - adding gesture recogniser to every UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

is it efficient for the app to add a gesture recogniser to every cell in a table view.
The cells can be as less as 10 or as much as 1000.

I mean will it effect scrolling behaviour, memory usage, and general stability?

And the cells are custom cells with 3 labels with different colors.

Thank you!

Comment: If you reuse your cells properly it wont be a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `UITableView` reuses cells the performance will be pretty much the same for 10 and 1000 cells (depends on how much fit on a single page of the table). Table cells already have gesture recognizers (the swipe to delete gesture), so you should have no problem doing so, too.

Comment: Thank you. Cell reusing - it's obvious.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you do it. Table cells memory management is very good, that's what the `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];` is all about. So if you made sure you didn't have hundreds of gesture recognizers then there shouldnt be a problem. Try and make it so that you only have as many as there are resuable cells.

Comment: Thank you Josh.I probably was going to add a gesture to all the cells, instead of only the reusable cells.